# ARIMA modelling

Tags: self-study, arma

How can an ARIMA (2,1,0) model be estimated without attempting to calculate the coefficients of the model? What info would I need for this estimation?

Issy

Comment: Estimating the model means calculating its coefficients. This is a nonsensical question

Answer (score 2):

Simply lag the variable three times and use regression to estimate the four coefficients. You have ethe choice of including a constant or not .

iF you have [1-B][1-PHI1*B**1 - PHI2*B**2]*Y(t)= a(t)

where B*Y(t)=y(t-1) and in general [B**k]*Y(t)= Y(t-k)

then mutiplying out you get

```
     y(t)=a + b*y(t-1)* + c*y(t-2) + d*y(t-3) + a(t)
```

Comment: Why do you have to lag the variables three times? Is that the same as to lag the first differences two times?

Comment: Can you explain this a little more @IrishStat

Comment: Thanks @IrishStat -making revision a lot easier. Just to confirm, if it was a ARIMA (3,1,0) model, would I lag the variable 4 times?  What would I do for a ARIMA (0,1,2) model?

Comment: Yes . for ARIMA (0,1,?) there is no simple regression equivalent as you areusing past errors as predictors. You need software like AUTOBOX to handle this correctly.